# switch statement in do while javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, do-while

I have the following conversion of c code. The original compiles on all c compilers that i tried; gcc, intel, Visual Studios.

However javascript complains about a do-while loop in javascript.

```
     var rindex=0;
     var lim=10;
     var res = 2;
     switch (res) {
        do {

            case 0: r[rindex] = uiColor; rindex++;
            case 3: r[rindex] = uiColor; rindex++;
            case 2: r[rindex] = uiColor; rindex++;
            case 1: r[rindex] = uiColor; rindex++;

        } while (rindex < lim);
    }
```

I can not seem to find a way yo do this in javascript with out changing the logic. Does javascript do not allow a do while in switch statements?

Comment: Why are you trying to use Duff's Device in Javascript? The fact that it gives you an error means that it isn't supported. C is one of the only languages you can do this in. Just use a simple loop, and worry about optimizing it further only if you run into actual performance issues.

Comment: `for (var i = res; i < lim; i++) r[i] = uiColor` ? Or am I missing a crucial part of the logic here?

Comment: @MOehm, you are not, other than that the asker is trying to implement a Duff's device here.

Comment: @Katie That is what this issue is. I already did this in a a standard loop. It is an RLE compressor/decompressor for bitmap. 
Thanks.

Comment: @EvrenBingøl, the normal solution (even in C) for manual loop unrolling is to break it into two loops. One to handle big chunks of unrolled statements, and another to finish up the leftovers one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Right, refer to JavaScript's [switch statement syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

```
switch (expression) {
  case value1:
    //Statements executed when the result of expression matches value1
    [break;]
  case value2:
    //Statements executed the result of expression matches value2
    [break;]
  ...
  case valueN:
    //Statements executed when the result of expression matches valueN
    [break;]
  default:
    //Statements executed when none of the values match the value of the expression
    [break;]
}
```

In fact, most languages define the `switch` statement this strictly. Implementing Duff's device this way requires a [relaxed specification of the `switch` statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device#Mechanism).